# nginx does not use modified index file

Tags: html, nginx

I installed nginx on my raspberry pi, and configured it.
However, it does not work as what I want.
The IP of raspberry pi is 192.168.0.182, so I made index.html fil and typed in my browser. But, it show nginx's default message, not my index.html.

[image]

If I use 192.168.0.182/index.html, it shows my index.html.

[image]

What I want it not to use "/index.html" after IP address for index.html. How shoud I configure nginx?

This is my nginx configuration in /etc/nginx/site-available.

```
server{
    listen 80;
    root /home/xaliver/Web/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

and I linked it by

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/mysite /etc/nginx/site-enalbled/
```

Also, I putted index.html in /home/xaliver/Web/www/. The index.html is

```
"Hello World"
```

Please, let me know what I missed.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually link it to `/site-enalbled/`, typo and all?

Comment: Yes, I did. This typo is only for this question. I checked mysite in /etc/nginx/site-enabled/.